Two different ways to calculate an integral produce different results. Which is correct and what is the error in the other method?
The problem is to calculate this integral:
$$I = \int \limits_{-1}^1 \frac{\sin \frac{2\pi}{5}}{x^2+2x \cos \frac{2\pi}{5} + 1} \mathrm{d}x$$
I produced 2 solutions - one pure mathematical, the other is a C# program that calculates this integral using the Monte-Carlo method of integration.
Unfortunately, the two solutions produce different results. I think that most likely the programmatic solution is correct, thus there must be some error in the pure mathematical solution.
Here is the mathematical solution:



The C# solution:
namespace ToughIntegral
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var r = new MyRandom();
            var hunderedM = Enumerable.Range(1, 100000000);
            long countPointsInArea = hunderedM
               .Select(k => r.PointUnderFunction(f)).Where(b => b).LongCount();
            var partOfWhole = countPointsInArea / 100000000.0;
            var area = 4 * partOfWhole;
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The area is {0:F6}", area));
        }

        public static readonly double pi = Math.PI;
        public static readonly double B = 0.4 * pi;
        public static readonly double sinB = Math.Sin(B);
        public static readonly double cosB = Math.Cos(B);

        static public double f(double x)
        {
            return sinB / (x * x + 2.0 * cosB * x + 1.0);
        }

        public class MyRandom : Random
        {
            public bool PointUnderFunction(Func<double, double> f)
            {
                var x = 2 * base.Sample() -1; // [-1, 1]
                var y = 2 * base.Sample();    // [0, 2]

                return y <= f(x);
            }
        }
    }
}

The result is: 1.57074496 and this is the result of the mathematical solution (1.6516329996) multiplied by sin(B) (0.95105651629)  . Here B is 2/5 * π
This means that in the math solution, when I divide by (sin(B))^2 I actually must only divide by sin(B).
I spent a long time trying to find any inconsistency in the mathematical solution - without success. :(
Could someone, please, point out which of the two computations (the mathematical and the programmatic) is correct, and what is the error in the incorrect one?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Why assume that either is correct?

I voted (-1) because you posted the equations as images. I edited the first equation using LateX. You can edit the rest of the question and I'll gladly give this an upvote :)

@infinitezero, Thank you for this information. Actually, this is my first question here, and I have already learned a lot. Nate Eldredge mentioned Sage, and now you brought in LateX. I was not aware about these tools, so thank you! I was actually planning to investigate what product exist that produce MathML results.

@PaulTanenbaum, Good question! I assume the C# program is producing the right result, because it is very simple and thus the chances for errors are small. And I have successfully used the same approach to produce correct (actually approximately-correct, because Monte-Carlo integration depends on "randomness" and might be more precise with a bigger number of random points) results. Not so about my integration techniques ... it was decades ago since I studied this at the university.

@DimitreNovatchev Why do you use MonteCarlo integration by the way? Why not Euler?

@infinitezero Good question again...
I have past experience using Monte-Carlo, and the code is extremely short and simple to write.
Could you, please, provide a link to any program implementation of Euler?

@DimitreNovatchev here is a very crude implementation: https://dotnetfiddle.net/irXkql I'm sure you can find ways to improve it.

@infinitezero Thank you, of course, one could implement this very basic/foundational and probably faster and more precise method of integration. But when we don't know the target in advance, we can only conclude that the result is "good" if the difference between results produced in consecutive iterations becomes less than a small number ε .

Well for most well-behaved functions, 1_000_000 steps should give you quite a good idea. You can also try Simpson's rule to increase accuracy or implement a recursive algorithm employing either method that automatically adjusts itself based on an estimated precision.

@infinitezero, Thanks, I am learning a lot here.

@infinitezero, Here is an implementation of Euler integration when the target is not known: https://dotnetfiddle.net/niq8Eo

@DimitreNovatchev that was a nice update. However, it is rather inefficient. That is not necessarily your fault, since Euler integration is very inefficient on its own. I've now written an example that uses Simpson integration and increases its own precision on the run, if needed. It deals badly with symmetric integrals, but works fine otherwise: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RfsKu2 in case of symmetric functions you will to split them up by hand first and integrate them in non-symmetric intervals.

For comparison: your code evaluates f  111_111_107 times. My code only needs 233 evaluations (and is more accurate to the analytic result). Have fun studying it :)

@infinitezero , It is not "your code vs my code" - it is Simpson vs Euler.
Your initial Euler implementation (https://dotnetfiddle.net/irXkql) runs approximately as fast as mine Euler implementation, and consumes 50% more memory :) Have fun, and thanks!

Your integral on line (1) is
$$I = \frac{1}{\sin \beta} \int \frac{1}{\left(\left(\frac{u}{\sin \beta}\right)^2+1\right)}\,du$$
and then you want to make the change of variables $v = \frac{u}{\sin \beta}$.  But in writing
$$I = \frac{1}{\sin \beta} \int\frac{1}{v^2+1}\,dv$$
you forgot that $du = \sin \beta \,dv$.  This would cancel the $\sin \beta$ in the denominator, so the correct integral is simply
$$I = \int \frac{1}{v^2+1}\,dv$$
This makes your overall answer off by a factor of $\frac{1}{\sin \beta} \approx 1.051462$ which matches the discrepancy between your symbolic and numerical answers.

Thank you so much Nate, You are a savior!
I upvoted this answer, and will accept it - SO tells me to wait 6 minutes before it will let me accept.
Yes, I did similar calculations veeery - looong time ago...

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\sin \frac{2 \pi}{5}}{x^2+2 x \cos \frac{2 \pi}{5}+1} d x 
& =\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\sin \left(\frac{2 \pi}{5}\right)}{\left(x+\cos \frac{2 \pi}{5}\right)^2+\sin ^2 \frac{\pi}{5}} d x \\
& =\frac{\sin \frac{2 \pi}{5}}{\sin \frac{2 \pi}{5}}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x+\cos \frac{2 \pi}{5}}{\sin \frac{2 \pi}{5}}\right)\right]_{-1}^1 \\
& =\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1+\cos \frac{2 \pi}{5}}{\sin \frac{2 \pi}{5}}\right)-\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{-1+\cos \frac{2 \pi}{5}}{\sin \frac{2 \pi}{5}}\right) \\
& =\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 \cos ^2 \frac{\pi}{5}}{2 \sin \frac{\pi}{5} \cos \frac{\pi}{5}}\right)+\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 \sin ^2 \frac{\pi}{5} }{2 \sin \frac{\pi}{5} \cos \frac{\pi}{5}}\right) \\
& =\tan ^{-1}\left(\cot \frac{\pi}{5}\right)+\tan ^{-1}\left(\tan \frac{\pi}{5}\right) \\
& =\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$
where the last answer comes from the identity : $\tan^{-1} x+\tan^{-1}\frac 1x= \frac{\pi}{2} . $
In general, for any $\sin a\ne 0$,
$$\boxed{\int_{-1}^1 \frac{\sin a}{x^2+2 x \cos a+1} d x =\frac \pi 2}$$

Interesting observation.  I wonder if there are other ways to see this.  For instance, if we differentiate under the integral sign with respect to $a$, is there some simple way to see that the resulting integral vanishes (e.g. symmetry)?
